# Pulling external website URL parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently I have a MVC Registration page which is implemented in an external website.

My question is I need to now extract the previous website's querystring for a certain parameter and read it into my page to register a user into the designated group.

So the workflow looks as follows :

- User hits the external website (example: www.test1.com/default.aspx?Code=123asd) with a code in the querystring
- user selects *Register Now* and gets directed to my page.

How will I be able to read the previous querystring code into my MVC page? I do not have access to that website.

***EDIT***

I currently have a foreach statement which reads the current querystring but this is not pulling the previous request's querystring:

```
private static string getCode()
    {
        string nothing = null;

        string[] queryStringParaArray = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Query.Substring(1).Split('=');

        if (queryStringParaArray.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var para in queryStringParaArray)
            {
                if (para.Contains("Code"))

                    return queryStringParaArray[2];
            }


        }
        return nothing;

    }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as MVC 7. What you want can also not be reliably implemented. The second best thing is if you can actually let the linking site append their query string to your URL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  [`HttpRequest.UrlReferrer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer(v=vs.110).aspx) property which contains URL of the client's previous request that linked to the current URL. This returns a `Uri` object and thus you can access the `Query` property to get the query string value of it.

```
HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer
```

**SideNote: As already commented, there is no guarantee that the referred URL would be present and thus it could be `null` as well. So would suggest you to pass that query string information directly to your MVC controller while clicking on `Register` button.

Comment: _If_ the client's configured to send that, _if_ the source site isn't HTTPS and _if_ you trust the client to not alter it, because it's a header the client sends (and thus can alter).

Comment: @CodeCaster, yes true ... added a note in answer

Comment: @Rahul I currently have that in a foreach statement to search for the parameter "Code". The querystring is not pulling the previous request through. I'll add the code as an edit on my Question

Comment: @RubenRedman, what does `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Query` gives?

Comment: @Rahul it returns the querystring where my page is hosted so where I want it to give - www.test1.com/default.aspx?Code=123asd and just return the value - 123asd, but currently it returns the querystring as follows - www.test2.com/default.aspx.